# Merge {pdf-reader} and {viewers}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The tags [pdf-reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-reader) and [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers) both contain the same kind of questions. [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers) is the more general tag (also allowing for dvi and ps viewers), so I think [pdf-reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-reader) should be merged into it.

Additionally, many of the [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers) questions are also tagged [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf), which is incorrect according to the [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf) tag wiki. Should the tag be removed or should the tag wiki be changed. (IMO, tagging something [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers)+[pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf) would make sense, so I'm for modifying the tag wiki.)

---

Since there doesn't seem to be any opposition, could some mod please do the merging. I'll add [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf) to the questions afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, combining tags for specific things like  {viewers} + {pdf} should be allowed.
We could change the last part of the [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf) tag from:

> If your question concerns PDF reader software, choose {pdf-reader} or a reader  specific tag such as {acrobat}, {evince} or {okular}.

to something like:

> If your question concerns PDF reader software, also add the {viewer} tag or  choose a reader specific tag such as {acrobat}, {evince} or {okular}.

The [pdf-reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-reader) can then made a synonym of [viewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewer). It's a pity that it can't be made a synonym of two tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think either we keep the tag [pdf-reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-reader) or we encourage using [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers) together with the format tag [pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf), [ps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps) or [dvi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi). It should be possible to filter the the viewer questions which are relevant for the format I'm using. I vote for the second option, one tag [viewers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewers) and suggested use with additional format tag.